# Change event not firing from dynamicly created checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I am creating checkboxes like this with JQuery:

```
var $checkbox = $('<input>', { type:'checkbox' });
$checkbox.change( function() { alert('changed'); });

$('body').append($checkbox);
```

My expectation is that when the checkboxes are clicked they should alert `changed` but they don't.

Why not?

Should I rather use `on` before I've even created them...?

Comment: add a fiddle link ....

Comment: Your code working fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/3qUMv/

Answer (score 0):

use event delegation on dynamic controls:

```
$(document).on('change',':checkbox',function(){
alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: His method should work, too. He's not using a selector, so delegation isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation - **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**, it attaches handler to elements matching the selector now or in future.

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){

});
```

Alternative is to use .**[delelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** which in turn uses .on().

Comment: While this is the preferred way to do it, binding the element explicitly should work, too.